# Single word for a market organiser

Tags: single-word-requests

Does anyone have a single word for one who organises a market?

Eg: NYSE Euronext Inc. is the ___________ behind NYSE and many other prominent financial markets.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a *market operator*.

> **Market Operator**
>   a person who manages and/or operates the business of a regulated market. The market operator may be the regulated market itself.
>   [- glossary, Financial Conduct Authority, FCA Handbook](https://www.handbook.fca.org.uk/handbook/glossary/?starts-with=M)

Here is a related use of the term in a different form (emphasis mine):

> NYSE Euronext, Inc. was a Euro-American multinational financial services corporation that **operated** multiple securities exchanges, including the New York Stock Exchange, Euronext and NYSE Arca (formerly known as ArcaEx).
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NYSE_Euronext)

Your sample sentence would then be:

> NYSE Euronext Inc. is the market operator behind NYSE and many other prominent financial markets.

Comment: *Was* (a financial services corporation). The example sentence is factually incorrect.

Comment: @Mazura Point noted (actually, it was already noted in the wikipedia quote :) ). The example sentence is the OP's - it's used just to discuss elements of English such as grammar and so on; in this case, an appropriate word for the role described. Please note that my answer doesn't offer any financial or corporate advice.

Comment: Thanks, Lawrence. I would've preferred a single word but obviously, that is the best we can do!

Answer (score 0):

[procurator](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procurator) you can can say that "A acts as a procurator for B. "

Answer (score 0):

[ICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercontinental_Exchange#NYSE_Euronext_2013) is the **parent** company of both subsidiaries: NYSE and NYSE Euronext.

> A [*subsidiary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsidiary), *subsidiary company* or *daughter company* is a company that is owned or controlled by another company, which is called the **parent company, parent, or holding company**. The subsidiary can be a company, corporation, or limited liability company. In some cases it is a government or state-owned enterprise. –Wiki

*NYSE Euronext Inc. and NYSE (and many other prominent financial markets) are all subsidiaries of their parent company: ICE.*

See also, [Conglomerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conglomerate_%28company%29) and [Types of business entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_business_entity).